# DynamoDB throwing an exception ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

In DynamoDB one of the table throws an error **ProvisionedThroughputExceededException**, I checked the spike in AWS and it was high however we have very less traffic, there are other tables that is being called using the AWS DynamoDB sdk without any issue.
I have activated WCU & RCU autoscaling from 1 to 20.

{"code":"ProvisionedThroughputExceededException","message":"The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.","httpStatusCode":400,"info":[]}

I've below code that is common for all, but for one table which is unexpected throwing an error, however, is it correct ??

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsByHashKeyAsync(object hashKeyValue, DynamoDBOperationConfig dynamoDBOperationConfig = null)
{
            return await context.QueryAsync<T>(hashKeyValue, dynamoDBOperationConfig).GetRemainingAsync();
}
```

Comment: Or consider DynamoDB [on-demand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand).

Comment: "Message: Throughput exceeds the current capacity of your table or index." Check if there is a Global Secondary Index that needs adjusting. Its throughput can also be exceeded.

Comment: @RossBush  how would a GlobalSecondaryIndex be causing throttling when using a Query on the table?

Comment: @LeeHannigan - I read up to where the read and write capacity of the table was updated to accommodate the needed throughput and wanted to point out that this exception could thrown when a global secondary on the table is used. I did not read the code. That is bad on my part :/ Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

> I checked the spike in AWS and it was high however we have very less traffic

This is the issue. DynamoDB emits metrics to CloudWatch at 1 min intervals, meaning the metrics you see are the average across a 60 second period. However, DynamoDB monitors throughput on a per-second basis. This means that it may seem like you did not exceed your provisioned throughput, but in actual fact you did for at least 1 second, the rest of the seconds in the minute could have a lower consumption meaning the CW metric is lower than you expect.

If you have sharp bursts in traffic, consider using on-demand mode where you will not get throttled for exceeding a provisioned capacity, it allows you to consume double your previous peak in 30 minutes.